# JPA Query get enum value

Tags: java, spring, jpa, enums

I've been going through many threads but none of them included an answer for my problem.

I got a single enum class:

```
public enum EActivationFunction {
  FKT_RELU("ReLU"),
  FKT_SIGMOID("Sigmoid"),
  FKT_TANH("Tanh"),
  FKT_LINEAR("Linear");

  @Getter private String name;

  EActivationFunction(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

That is used in the normal ActivationFunction class:

```
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(length = 20)
  private EActivationFunction type;
```

My query shortened:

```
 @Query(
      "SELECT f FROM MlpConfig f WHERE f.user = :user AND com.project.customMlp.domain.enumeration.EActivationFunction like %:searchQuery%")
```

So I tried full qualified name which does not work at all. When I query like this it works but not the name is used but the enum itself so FKT_RELU instead of relu:

```
lower(f.activationFunction.type)
```

ActivationFunction is another foreign entity of the main entity MlpConfig. How can I get the name? So normally:

```
f.activationFunction.type.name
```

Comment: Ummm... you do understand that JPQL gets translated to SQL and *then* executed, right? Ask yourself how you would write a SQL query to satisfy your current requirement

Answer (score 0):

In JPA, an Enum value can be mapped to its enum name or ordinal value. So the user-defined member variable of the enum type is invisible to JPA.